# Mostrar un formato de fecha diferente DataTable jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables, momentjs

Saludos me ocupa lo siguiente:

Tengo el siguiente script para DataTable

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
     listar();
 });



var listar = function(){

//$.fn.datatable.moment('DD MMMM YYYY');


    var table = $('#dt_billetera').DataTable({
        "dom": '<"top"pl>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
    "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        "language": idioma_espanol,
         "ajax": {
            "method":"POST",
            "url":"funciones/listar_b.php"
         },
        "columns":[
            {"data":"id"},

            {
      "data":"fecha",
      "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
              return data;
          }
        },
            {"data":"monto"},

            {"data": "descripcion"},
      {"data": "status"}
        ],

        drawCallback: function () {
                $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                        "html": true,
                        trigger: 'hover',
                        placement: 'auto',

                })
        }

    });
}


var idioma_espanol = {
    "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
    "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
    "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
    "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
    "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
    "sUrl":            "",
    "sInfoThousands":  ",",
    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst":    "Primero",
        "sLast":     "Último",
        "sNext":     "Siguiente",
        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
    },
    "oAria": {
        "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    }
}

</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/locale/es-us.min.js" integrity="sha512-QfUPyAMVgJBoL2yYVx8xkXmPFL7IKoF+eP5hq5xF4O/Mz1eqvxdy/vBEWDiJNPwGw7K8FCcCllrppqLpSWK/ng==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

He intentado cambiar el formato de salida de la fecha incluyendo la biblioteca **moment.js** pero me da un error

he usado `$.fn.datatable.moment('DD MMMM YYYY');` y la consola del navegador Google Chrome me da este error:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: $.fn.DataTable.moment is not a function
> TypeError: $.fn.DataTable.moment is not a function

El dato viene de MySQL y el formato de origen es de tipo timestamp

se obtiene con un codigo

```
   $arreglo ["data"][] = $data;
 }

 echo json_encode($arreglo);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal vez te interese leer [You probably don't need Moment.js anymore](https://dockyard.com/blog/2020/02/14/you-probably-don-t-need-moment-js-anymore), porque Javascript te provee funciones para formato de fechas a través del [objeto Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) y el método [.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString); de hecho, el artículo está enlazado desde la documentación de [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) acompañado de esta recomendación:

> We recognize that many existing projects may continue to use Moment, but we would like to discourage Moment from being used in new projects going forward.

En español:

> Reconocemos que muchos proyectos existentes aún pueden usar Moment, pero desaconsejamos su uso en nuevos proyectos.

En la definición de la columna puedes formatear el valor directamente con la propiedad [render](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html). Considerando lo que expones en la pregunta:

> El dato viene de MySQL y el formato de origen es de tipo timestamp

La fecha está en segundos y debe convertirse a milisegundos para poder trabajarla con el objeto `Date`:

```
    {
        data: "fecha",
        render: function(data, type, row) {
            // Se debe multiplicar por 1000, porque Date considera milisegundos
            return new Date(data * 1000).toLocaleDateString(
               'es-MX', // Ajusta tu idioma y país
               {
                   year: 'numeric',
                   month: 'long',
                   day: 'numeric'
               }
           );
        }
    }
```

Ejemplo funcionando:

```js
// 2021-05-10 = 1620662809 segundos
let data = 1620662809;
// Se debe multiplicar por 1000, porque Date considera milisegundos
console.log(new Date(data * 1000).toLocaleDateString(
               'es-MX', // Ajusta tu idioma y país
               {
                   year: 'numeric',
                   month: 'long',
                   day: 'numeric'
               }
           )); // 10 de mayo de 2021
```

Comment: Definitivamente Genial como siempre hermano, en mi caso utilice `return new Date(data).toLocaleDateString(` sin multiplicar por 1000 porque el dato ya viene convertido. y funciono de forma perfecta..! Muy bien documentada logre comprender y logicamente acabo de quitar las bibliotecas moment.js que ya no las necesito, Gracias por tu respuesta y muy agradecido por tu tiempo..!